# Create text at click location onclick

Tags: javascript, html, text

So I need text to appear at the location I click in a program I'm working on, problem is I have absolutely no idea how to do it. So my questions are:

- Is this possible?
- If so, what can I do to achieve this result?

Thanks for any guidance <3 I'm currently using javascript but if I require a plugin like jquery to do this, I'm open to suggestions.

**More detail**: when I click on a canvas, anywhere on it - I want the ability to output text at that location. Eventually I will have separate texts appear above, below, left and right of the click location so the user knows what forces are coming from where.

Comment: If you use a textarea instead of a canvas you can place text at the cursor position

Comment: So you want to write text in the canvas? Not in an other HTML element?

Comment: @putvande Yes if I could write the text in the canvas that would be ideal. There are pictures in the canvas that I need to describe with text. That's why I need the text on the canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could get the clientX and clientY of the mouseclick position with your own function using the javascript addEventListener method. once you get the position of the mouseclick, you could use javascript.createElement("P") and position that element exactly where you want it. look more into these two links: http://www.kirupa.com/html5/getting_mouse_click_position.htm and http://www.htmlforums.com/html-xhtml/t-putting-text-in-a-specific-location-129657.html. an example code could be this

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var body = document.body;
body.addEventListener("click", getPosition);

function getPosition(e)
{
     var x = e.clientX;
     var y = e.clientY;
     document.write("<p id='add'>TEXT</p>");
     var text = document.getElementById('add');
     text.style.position = "absolute";
     text.style.top = y;
     text.style.left = x;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and if you wanted to change the text that you added^, you could add a line that said text.textContent = whateveryouwant; or simply change it on the document.write line

Comment: also if the text appears slightly under the cursor, set margin:0 and padding:0 for style (text.style.margin=0;text.style.padding=0;)

Comment: This method works, but it opens the text in a new page as document.write automatically utilises document.open, is it possible to write the text in the same page?

Comment: really? when i tested it, it opened in the same page

Comment: maybe try doing this: var p = document.createElement("p"); p.id = "add"; body.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", p); instead of document.write

Answer (score 0):

You can get the click location like below and use that to place your text.

```
$("#myButton").click(function(e) {
    alert(e.clientX + ", "+ e.clientY);
})

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", getPosition, false);

function getPosition(event)
{
  var x = event.x;
  var y = event.y;    
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");    
  x -= canvas.offsetLeft;
  y -= canvas.offsetTop;
}
```